# How to Click second button on IE with VBA that have same id but different onclick element

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I try to click a button in IE that have same ID, same class but different onclick. My code work with 1st button but cannot click on 2nd button.
 Onclick element will call function `RaiseGdcP1(ItemLineNo)`.

I already try to use `IHTMLElement` to loop my code to search for Id `btnGdcP1`and click all that id but failed.

Here code that i use to click 1st button

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGdcP1").Click
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
```

Html is as below

```
<INPUT onclick=RaiseGdcP1(2) id=btnGdcP1 type=button value="GDC P1" name=btnGdcP1> "1st button
<INPUT onclick=RaiseGdcP1(3) id=btnGdcP1 type=button value="GDC P1" name=btnGdcP1> "2nd button
```

Even in my excel I have 2 line for each button.
My code above only able to click 1st button only.
I would like to click both of button.
Can you me help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute = value selectors to differentiate

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='RaiseGdcP1(2)']").click
```

You may need to escape the () e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='RaiseGdcP1\(2\)']").click
```

but I don't think so. I think escaping is for when unquoted e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick=RaiseGdcP1\(2\)]").click
```

For the other

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='RaiseGdcP1(3)']").click
```

---

You can also use querySelectorAll() with # id selector

```
Dim buttons As Object
Set buttons = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#btnGdcP1")
buttons.item(0).click '< first
buttons.item(1).click '< second
```

---

You might also be able to call functions direct

```
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "RaiseGdcP1(1)"
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "RaiseGdcP1(3)"
```

Comment: i will try last option. I also want try if able to use variable.
`ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "RaiseGdcP1(i)"`

Comment: you can concantenate i  into all of the above if using i variable for index. You can also pass to querySelectorAll("#btnGdcP1").item(i).click '<index starts as 0 for first button

Comment: thank you. I think it work with querySelectorAll(). Try with call function, failed.

Comment: I try it but got error on line `buttons.Item(j).Click '< first` run time error 424 object required

Answer (score 0):

It is an error to have two id's with the same value. It must be unique in order to work as expected: 
https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_id.asp

Change the second id to a unique value (btnGdcP2) and use that in your code:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGdcP1").Click
HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGdcP2").Click
```

Comment: you mean change it in web?

Comment: That is not strictly true. You can have the same id repeated.

Comment: @Ruzaini: Change in your HTML code and in the javascript.

Comment: @QHarr: Yes you can, it will not yield an error  but it defies the purpose of id uniqueness. What return value will you expect from getElementById(multipleSameIDs)?

Comment: I would use any of the methods I use in my answer. If I had control of the html itself (owned the website) - that would be a different matter.

Comment: @peakpeak I afraid i not able to change in HTML code. Because the web is handle by other organization.

Comment: @Ruzaini: Ok, you did not mention that.

Comment: @peakpeak sorry about that